# Why isn't this sorting function working in Safari?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, safari

I wrote a function that sorts an array of arrays based on the second element of each subarray. For example:

Sorting:

```
var x = [['car', 10], ['dog', 20], ['horse', 2]]
```

Should return `[[ 'dog', 20 ], [ 'car', 10 ], [ 'horse', 2 ]]`

I tried this function in Chrome and Firefox and it works just fine. For some reason when I try it out in Safari the resulting array isn't sorted. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Here is the function:

```
     x = x.sort(function(a,b){
  return a[1] < b[1];
})
```

Comment: Please read documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value smaler than zero, zero or greater than zero. Please see the documentation probably [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description).

This proposal returns the difference of the values of the items which are acually compared. An while the sortorde is descrending, we need to subtract value of a from b.

```
function(a, b){
    return b[1] - a[1];
});
```

Example:

```js
var x = [['car', 10], ['dog', 20], ['horse', 2]];
x.sort(function(a,b){
    return b[1] - a[1];
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Btw, no need to assign the result. Sorting is working *in place*.

Comment: Ok thanks, that works. Any idea why it worked on Chrome/Firefox but it didn't work on Safari?